# Two CLI for one process

Tags: java, chat, command-line-interface

Is it possible to create for only one process two different CLI (CommandLineInterface)?
I would like to have one CLI with my real program, and another CLI for a chat, so that i can send command to my program and send messages in the chat at the same time, and obviously have different views for the program and the chat.

(edit)
the program is a game and the chat is to make communication between all player, but when i start my program in eclipse, that program strat with only a console and here i would like to have two console in one there is the game with its action and state and in the other one i would like to have all the messages in the chat.
I know that i can build another process from zero and integrate it with process builder, but i would like to have all in one process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I assume that by CLI you mean the main terminal from where you execute your program, the answer is NO, regardless the OS.

There are couple of options to implement additional CLI interfaces in the same process:

- listening on socket and waiting for client(s) to connect by e.g. telnet
- opening a window that implements the CLI
- under UNIX you can spawn e.g. a xterm and process its IO in your process

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux or OSX, just open a new terminal window, and you will have an additional CLI to work with, and yes, you can try your program from those two different environments simultaneously and independently.

Under Windows, I couldn't say. You're probably using cygwin or something like that, so you should probably try to be a bit more specific in your question to get more attention.